# Rewrite rule for subdomain

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system

I want to ensure that all URLs on my subdomain use HTTPS.

For my main domain, I use this and it works fine:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
ServerName example.io
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
</VirtualHost>
```

However, if I try this for my subdomain like below:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName demo.example.io
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/demo
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
</VirtualHost>
```

I get redirected to my main site (i.e., subdomain is stripped off) so demo.example.io becomes example.io. Any ideas what is going on here?

UPDATE:

I removed the redirects from my httpd.conf and instead put the rules into my .htaccess file.

It has this now:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}? [R=301,L]
```

This redirects http://example.com to https://example.com but it redirects http://demo.example.com to https://demo.example.comdemo (with the subdomain stuck on the end of the URL).

Does this help point out the problem?

Comment: The rewrite rules don't look like they should be causing that behavior. Is it possible that the the first virtual host is processing all requests? Can you set up logging for each VHost and see if requests for demo.example.io are writing to the demo.example.io log file and not the example.io log file? This page has example on how to do it if you've not done it before: http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/ExampleVhosts

Comment: @jotap Thanks for the suggestion. Before I tackle this, can you look at my edited response and see if you have a different suggestion?

Comment: it looks like it should work fine, the evidence so far points to some other rewriting happening as well. Is it possible to turn up logging for mod_rewrite and we'll see what's going on? This shows how to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9632852/how-to-debug-apache-mod-rewrite